# Android icons not scaling correctly

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In my toolbar/support action bar the navigation icon resolution is not scaling correctly
I'm also having the same problem with a third party library I'm using for tabs (I've tried a few libraries which produce the same result)
I set the navigation icon programatically like this...

```
mToolbarView = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbarView.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.nav_icon);
    //mToolbarView.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbarView);
```

Which ends up looking like this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-fCQa73GiDYWmJwaFh3U0pFT1E/view?usp=sharing

I'm running my app on Galaxy Note 3 btw

I would ultimately like my tab icons to look like this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-fCQa73GiDYakg3M3doclY5SEU/view?usp=sharing

My icons are stored under Res > Mipmap in individual folder (hdpi, mdpi, xdip...)

If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You should check the dimensions of your png files. I also would recommend using svg format for icons like that.

Comment: Yes I think it's the dimensions of the icons. To get the right dimension go to this website and put them through the action bar and tab icons. You should get all the correct sizes for the different resolutions. https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: @Mood SVG is not really supported.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski thx for pointing that up. I forgot to mention that for now it's not officially supported on pre Lollipop versions, but there are some third party libraries, while waiting for the official support library.

Comment: I know but my point is that you need to rasterize svg and despite clear benefits from using vector format it is still less painful to have PNGs in your app

Comment: I actually got my icons straight from the  website https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ and check that the (mdpi, hdpi, xdpi, xxdpi) dimensions were correct....thats the part that the most frustrating

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your drawable placement. Mipmap folder is just for app icons. Dont' place any other drawables here. You have to place other drawables in there respective drawable directories.   As described [here.](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
Instead of getting my icons from the action bar tabs section
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html

I was getting my icons from launcher section 
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

hence the disproportionate resolutions